# Serialize parameters of trigger into string

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Say we are inside a trigger and we want to log the props of `:New` or `:Old` placeholders.basic way of doing this is simply concatenating prop names and their corresponding values one by one like this :

```
somevar := 'col1:' || :New.col1 || 'col2:' || :New.col2 , ...
```

is there any function accepting `:new` as input and serializing it's member as sequence of key-value pairs?

Comment: Can't be done. `:new` is a namespace not a record. You could generate the trigger from the data dictionary USER_TAB_COLS view, which would save you some typing, especially if you need to do this on multiple tables.

Comment: would it be possible if it was a record?if yes how?

Comment: There is no Oracle built-in which takes a record type and spits out a string of KV pairs.